# Two Way Calendar Sycnhro'

Tags: calendar

This is an old problem, but there must be an answer : two way calendar synchronisation.

I don't use Google. I have Outlook. Ubuntu 20.10. Thunderbird / Lightening and Evolution. I have never got two way calendar Synch' working with Outlook. I don't MS support two way.

What is the best way / most common way to get some two way calendar Synch service that will work with T'bird / Evolution ?

I would like to have something centralised, that I can access through the web, but also allows two way synch' through T'Bird, and through my mobile [Android, de-googled] but, I'll live without mobile synch' if I can get everything else two way synch'ed.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Thunderbird+Lightning works fine with Caldav, any caldav service will do.

Comment: Evolution also works fine with CalDAV. The question is if Microsoft supports CalDAV.

Comment: Evolution(+EWS)  works also okayish with Exchange server.